# 'Required' attribute not working on MailChimp sign up form

Tags: html, forms, validation

I'm creating a really basic sign up form with Mailchimp that I Embedd into my site.

I have included `required` attribute to the form. When submitted a popup will appear "Please fill in this field". Unfortunately this does not work.

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
                <form action=""
                    method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank"
                    novalidate>
                    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                        <div class="mc-field-group">
                            <label class="required" for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address</span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" required />
                        </div>
                        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text"
                                name="b_2e4b9b144fbbafc48f6f8a2a5_800e0efef3" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                        <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe"
                                class="button"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

However something as simple as this does work:

```
<code class="hljs xml"><form>
    <input type="email" required /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Now!">
</form></code>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `novalidate` form attribute specifies that the form should not be validated when submitted. This has been now removed.